# Cosmonaut (CosmosDb) - Query does not working

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I try to query CosmosDb by using Cosmonaut. I follow its documentation to know better how to [read/query](https://cosmonaut.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Reading-and-Querying.html)

Here is my method in a repo

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Object>> GetAsync(GetObjects query)
    {

        try
        {
            var result = await _objectStore.Query().ToListAsync();
            //var testOne= await _objectStore.Query(new FeedOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(query.foo) }).ToListAsync();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

It is so strange that when I hit the below line, it terminates without throwing any exception and therefore it makes it hard to know what is the issue.

```
 var result = await _objectStore.Query().ToListAsync();
 //var testOne= await _objectStore.Query(new FeedOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(query.foo) }).ToListAsync();
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Is `Object` some other POCO object or is it the C# class `Object`?

Comment: Some other POCO. It is the exact class which I use as CollectionName

Comment: That is very bizarre. Looks like a deadlock but I can't understand why you would get one unless you are doing a `.Result` somewhere upstream.

Comment: It was a helpful point. I was calling the repo without await. @NickChapsas what was happening in the background?

Comment: @NickChapsas I mean why it was terminating on _objectStore line?